# View for Organic Group CCK field

Tags: 6, entities, organic-groups

I'm trying to create a View that displays a CCK Imagefield from an Organic Group node.

I have a content type called 'Subsite' that I'm using as the Organic Groups creation node. I've added a CCK Imagefield called "Banner" to this content type, so that each group has a banner image.

I'm creating 'Page' nodes and assigning them to Organic Groups.

Let's say I assign a page called "Page 1" to the OG "Group 1." How can I configure a View to display the banner on "Page 1"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view, you only need to bring up the node's parent group and display its banner field:

**Add relationships:** Organic groups: Group node (post)
**Add fields:** Content: Group banner, Relationship: Group node (post)